# MYSQL Workbench cannot connect

Tags: mysql, sql

When I test MySQL workbench connection it come up with "Cannot connect to MySQL server 127.0.0.1 (10061)

Also when I right click to create a schema it crashes - every time.

I have tried a re-install, no-luck.

[Image of the connection error(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wt7nU.png)      [Server not running (top right(2))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxGMm.png)

I AM ON WINDOWS 10

Comment: Have you checked the service has started?

Comment: In my program files I only have MySQL no MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Please check legal documentation for "Starting MySQL as a Windows Service".
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/windows-start-service.html

Comment: It's for MySQL 2.3.3.7 though. I am using MySQL 6.3

Comment: 2.3.3.7 is a title number of that document not MYSQL version. MYSQL version is 5.5.
Also you can not use MYSQL 6.3 because it does not exists. 6.3 is your WorkBench version.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.6.html

Install from that link, and in the wizard, select developer install